# Is PackageExport a command in Linux?

Tags: command, programming

Does anyone know if PackageExports is a command in Linux? or where can one install its package?

When I tried to install the package `SemidefiniteProgramming`, to [Macaulay 2](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/), in Gnu/Linux, I always get an error message `error: encountered an unknown key or option: PackageImports`.

Comment: It's not a shell built-in command, it might a part of an external program but in that case could you post a link to it?

Comment: We can't really answer this. Any programmer anywhere in the world could have written something called PackageExports which runs on Linux. Please [edit] your question and give us some context. Why do you think this is a Linux command? Where did you see it referenced? What is it supposed to do?

Comment: If you just want list of installed apps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages But now snaps & flatpacks are separate lists.

Comment: @terdon When I tried to install a package to a software, specifically SemidefiniteProgramming package to Macaulay 2, in Linux, I always got an error message "error: encountered an unknown key or option: PackageImports". So could you help me install it or fix the error? Thanks.

Comment: Linux is the kernel. It has no commands. The commands like in user-land. Part of a Gnu/Linux operating-system. To know if it is part of a distribution, we would need to know which distribution. And what the command is. Please edit the question, to tell us: What operating system (distribution) you are using/considering, and what this "Package Exports" is.

Comment: I have moved your comment into the question (you can also edit the question). However the question is still not clear. **Show** us what you did, and what happened. What command did you issue to do the install?

Comment: What **version** of Macaulay2 are you using? according to [changes, 1.5](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/doc/Macaulay2-1.15/share/doc/Macaulay2/Macaulay2Doc/html/_changes_cm_sp1.5.html) that was when *"The function newPackage now has two new options, PackageExports and PackageImports..."*

Comment: @steeldriver Thank you for you comment. Mine is 1.3. Could you please help me with how to update Macaulay? Thanks.

Comment: @steeldriver By the way, I got a message that contains "Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.19)(64bit)". So how to get libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.19)(64bit) successfully installed in CentOS? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments:

> By the way, I got a message that contains `Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.19)(64bit)`. So how to get libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.19)(64bit) successfully installed in CentOS?

If you are running CentOS 7.x, the message means you'll need to install the `libstdc++` package first. (If you have an internet connection, you could use `yum localinstall <Macaulay2 rpm file>` and it would automatically know about the dependency and offer to download and install it for you.)

But if you have CentOS 6.x, the message suggests you're attempting to install a Macaulay2 package that is intended for CentOS 7.x only.

Adding CentOS 7.x's `libstdc++` package to CentOS 6.x without updating the entire system from 6.x to 7.x is not supported and would create a mess of package dependencies. Don't do it.

Instead, find the Macaulay2 packages for CentOS 6.x at: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Repositories/Scientific/6/index.html

But you may want to [download the Macaulay2-6.repo file](https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/Macaulay2/Downloads/GNU-Linux/Red%20Hat%20Enterprise,%20CentOS,%20Scientific%20Linux/Macaulay2-6.repo), place it in `/etc/yum.repos.d/` directory, and then run `sudo yum install Macaulay2` instead. This should automatically install the most up-to-date version of Macaulay2 available for CentOS 6.x and any necessary dependencies from the CentOS official repositories.

Note that the last version suitable for CentOS 6.x is version 1.8.2, and it was initially built for Scientific Linux 6.6 in July 2015. The versions for CentOS 7.x are more up to date, so you might want to consider updating your system from CentOS 6.x to 7.x if possible. Still, version 1.8.2 is newer than 1.5 so it should support the PackageImports option.

Also note that the Macaulay2 repositories are not cryptographically signed (the published `.repo` files have `gpgcheck=0`), so the authenticity of the contents cannot be automatically verified. Manually verifiable `.sig` files are available for Centos 7.x's versions only. Use at your own risk.